# Supersized jQuery plugin - only some background images shown

Tags: jquery, html-lists, supersized

All of my background images load until i try to put in an image overlay for each slide. The problem occurs when I tag my ul with `id="supersized"`

Once I do this only my background images on slides 1, 2, and 9 load. 3-8 only show the background color and the overlay image.

I've pinpointed the problem with firebug but do not know how to fix it

```
<ul id="supersized" class="quality" style="visibility: visible;">
<li class="activeslide">
<div class="overlay-holder">
<div class="img">
<img src="../../images/homeimg.png" style="width: 1024px; left: 0px; top: -187px;">
</div>
</div>
<a target="_blank">
<img src="http://schochink.com/IMG_21562.jpg" style="width: 1024px; left: 0px; top: -188.5px; height: 686.08px;">
</a>
</li>
<li class="activeslide">
<div class="overlay-holder">
<div class="img">
<img src="../../images/aboutimg.png" style="width: 1024px; left: 0px; top: -101.5px;">
</div>
</div>
<a target="_blank">
<img src="http://schochink.com/IMG_26922.jpg" style="width: 1024px; left: 0px; top: -    188.5px; height: 686.08px;">
</a>
</li>
<li class="activeslide">
<div class="overlay-holder">
<div class="img">
<img src="../../images/homeimg.png" style="width: 1024px; left: 0px; top: -187px;">
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

Here is my actual html, the above was what firebug showed me

```
<ul id="supersized">
  <li class="">
    <div class="overlay-holder">
        <div class="img">
        <img src="../../images/homeimg.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="">
    <div class="overlay-holder">
        <div class="img">
        <img src="../../images/aboutimg.png" />
         </div>
     </div>

  </li>
  <li class="">
    <div class="overlay-holder">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="../../images/Untitled-2.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="">
    <div class="overlay-holder">
        <div class="img">
        <img src="../../images/homeimg.png" />
        </div>
    </div>

  </li>
  <li class="">
  <div class="overlay-holder">
        <div class="img">
        <img src="../../images/homeimg.png" />
    </div>
  </div>

  </li>
  <li class="">
  <div class="overlay-holder">
        <div class="img">
        <img src="../../images/homeimg.png" />
    </div>
  </div>

  </li>
  <li class="">
  <div class="overlay-holder">
        <div class="img">
        <img src="../../images/homeimg.png" />
    </div>
  </div>

  </li>
  <li class="">
  <div class="overlay-holder">
        <div class="img">
        <img src="../../images/homeimg.png" />
    </div>
  </div>

  </li>
  <li class="">
  <div class="overlay-holder">
        <div class="img">
        <img src="../../images/homeimg.png" />

        </div>
  </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm pretty new to jquery but i think this is what adds the anchor tag. correct me if im wrong

```
/* Place Supersized Elements
----------------------------*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<div id="supersized-loader"></div><ul id="supersized"> </ul>');
});
```

Comment: to clarify the issue is that when the jquery plugin only adds the "a" tag to the first two images and the ninth one for some reason. I only put the first three up as to not overwhelm with code.

Answer (score 0):

Your divs are not closed which is probably causing issues.

Update:
First of all on the page you're having two elements with the same ID: "supersized". Do you see this? Inspect the elements after load to see it. Also you're .png-s are loaded correctly, however homeimg.png has transparent background, which is why you see the background color.

Comment: they are on my html document though. Any idea why they are getting lost when i view the site live?

Comment: If your site is live, can you provide a link to the page that has the problem?

Comment: sorry i mispoke, when i view it locally that is what happens

Comment: I just put it to my personal site if you don't mind giving it a look. Sorry for my messy code... I have some housekeeping to do.

http://schochink.com/buildinternet-supersized-dfa4c5b/slideshow/slide.html#

Comment: What is the jQuery code which adds the anchor tags for you? Can you post that as well?

Comment: First of all on the page you're having two elements with the same ID:
"supersized". Do you see this? Also you're .png-s are loaded correctly, however homeimg.png has transparent background, which is why you see the background color.

Comment: do you know a way that I can get the overlay images to appear only on the slider tab that i specify?

Comment: or simply repeat the supersized id in the plugin with a different id name?

Comment: Yeah use a different ID for this I guess

Comment: okay, i just dont really know how to set that up in my javascript. jquery and javascript are very new to me. If you have any suggestions it would be much appreciated. If not thanks for all of your help already!

Comment: Basically the Supersized plugin adds the markup for you (at least this is my understanding). You wouldn't need to add anything for it to work.